# PHP & MySQL - Prepared Statements won't return a specific column

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm writing a website using PHP and MySQL and I'm using the following code to select everything from the table where ID is 0 or 1.
However, when I dump $op it appears as an empty string even though in the PhpMyAdmin it's not.
All other columns are displayed as expected except this one.
Anyone know what's wrong?

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM `artikli` WHERE `id` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('d',$id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id,$pl,$pr,$slika,$ime,$op);
$stmt->fetch();
var_dump($op);
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your code. most likely this column is empty indeed

Comment: try to add `var_dump($stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc());` before  bind_result

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use that since I'm using a hosting provider which doesn't have MySQL native driver

Comment: there is very little you can do anyway. mysqli doesn't rewrite your fields.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

### Answer

I figured it out guys.
Free hosting is free for a reason.
I've downloaded the website to my local machine and now it works perfectly.